# Windows Explorer settings: What's the point of SSF_SHOWSYSFILES?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, windows-explorer

I'm trying to detect the show system and hidden files settings from Windows Explorer in an application I'm writing.  I'm using [SHGetSetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762200(VS.85).aspx) and in calling it I have to specify one or more of the [SSF Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762591%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to specify what settings to retrieve.

Finding out the hidden files settings was easy enough, I just had to specify `SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS` to retrieve that setting.  As for the system files setting, I'm a bit confused between `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES` and `SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN`.  It appears that "Hide protected operating system files" in Explorer's "Folder Options" maps to `SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN`, but I can't find any setting that appears to map to `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES`.

Does anyone know what `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES` is used for or why it's there?  Is it just a legacy setting that is no longer used in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774120%28VS.85%29.aspx):

(SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS)
The state of the Show hidden files and folders option.

(SSF_SHOWSYSFILES)
The state of the Do not show hidden files and folders option.

(SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN)
The state of the Hide protected operating system files option.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Do you mean that `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES` is the new setting and the `SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN` is the legacy setting?  I'm using Windows 7 and whenever I check/uncheck "Hide protected operating system files", it changes `SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN`, but I can't find anything that changes `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES`, it always comes back `false`.

Comment: Thanks! The MSDN link (although for `IShellDispatch4`) explains it very well, and experimentation confirms that is correct for `SHGetSetSettings` as well.  It looks like `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES` is essentially the opposite of `SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS`, so I don't need to worry about checking `SSF_SHOWSYSFILES`.